# File transfer via XMPP (Openfire)

Tags: xmpp, file-transfer, openfire

I'm trying to implement file transfer via xmpp, my server is openfire 3.9.3.

I have tried to imitate Sparks' stanzas and I got to a dead end.
please help!

Answer (score 1):

file transfer is already implemented in xmpp servers like openfire.

You need to implement it in client side.
Check strophe js or candy js, there is an API to do this.